# jquery is not working or angular js nghide show not working in angular routing page

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ngroute

i am using angular 1.6 routing and in ng-view i am showing my routing page data, but in routing pages my jquery code and angular code for hide and show are not working please help me. i am new in angularjs.

```
<style>
.image-upload > input {
    display:none;
}
.edit-picture {
 position: absolute;
left: 46.5%;
top: 32%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
.edit-picture {
position: absolute;
left: 46.5%;
top: 78%;
 }
 }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#profile-button").click(function(){
    $("#2").show(1000);
    $("#1").hide(1000);
   });
  });
</script>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-10" ng-controller="profile">
   <div class="text-center">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="pull-right">
         <a id="profile-button"> <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x" style="cursor:pointer;color:#f7972f;"> </i> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="image-upload edit-picture">
            <label for="file-input">
                <i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x" style="cursor:pointer;color:#f7972f;"> </i>
            </label>
            <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
          </div>
          <img src="amit.jpg" class="img img-circle edit-image" style="width:150px;">
             <h3> Amit Singh Chauhan </h3>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-12"  id="1"> 
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10" >
        This is detail Section
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"  id="2" style="display: none;"> 
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-10" >
        <form action="" novalidate="novalidate">
            <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap first-name"><input type="text" name="first-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="First Name"></span></p>
            <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap last-name"><input type="text" name="last-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Last Name"></span></p>
            <p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email-address"><input type="email" name="email-address" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="E-mail Address"></span></p>
            <div><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Comment"></textarea></span></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Save Profile" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit mkd-contact3"><span class="ajax-loader"></span></div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please detail your `controller` code and also can't see  use of `ng-show\ng-hide` in your html.

Comment: Do not mix AngularJS with jQuery!

Comment: Where is AngularJS?

Comment: i tried using angular nghide show but its not work so i prefer to jquery bt that also not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set ng-click for button , and ng-show for you want show or hide . example

```
<button ng-click ="clickme()">Click</button>
<div ng-show="show1">abc</div>
<div ng-show="show2">def</div>
```

in js file and you should put ng-app in html . `<html ng-app="yourapp">`

**EDIT**

```
  (function(){
            angular.module('yourapp',[])
                    .controller('yourcontroller',yourcontroller);
                    yourcontroller.$inject =['$scope','$timeout'];
                    function yourcontroller($scope,$timeout){
                        $scope.show1 = true;
                        $scope.show2=false;
                        $scope.clickme = function(){
    $timeout(function(){
    $scope.show1 =!$scope.show1;
    $scope.show2=!$scope.show2
    },1000);
    }
                    }
        })()
```

and in your config route

```
  .when("/profile", {
        templateUrl : "profile.php",
        controller : "profilecontroller"
}
```

Comment: i am using this hide show in routed page so its not working

Comment: in my header file i  use this

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"/>
        <link rel="pingback" href="xmlrpc.php"/>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        
 <title>project title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="route.js"></script>

Comment: ok.. i am using angular routing in which there are 3 to 4 pages which i routed . in one of them is profile.php in which i want to hide and show div so i am using nghide and show but its not working in that page

Comment: @amitchauhan i cant see where `#1` and `#2` off you . But easy way is you add ng-show like my example and it , and in js file doing same with me

Comment: in my header i call angular.min, route.min and app.js containing your code in which you are using clickme function

Comment: i remove jquery code and put your angular code in my app.js file

Comment: still not helping

Comment: @amitchauhan can you post full your code , route.js and app.js , i want see it

Comment: @amitchauhan check your controller in page you route want use it . And if you want use it all page . change `$scope` -> `$rootScope`

Comment: i tried to upload important files for this project hope you can find it now

Comment: @amitchauhan read only i cant fix it , but you remove ng-controller in profile.html and add in config route , i edited answer , check it

Comment: @amitchauhan here is example i create , you can see it work https://plnkr.co/edit/lYmLW5vYAcD5EqlAEbVY?p=preview

Comment: i can do that also in my main page but in routed page i cant

Comment: i test my code in seperate file and its working problem occurs only with routed pages

Comment: @amitchauhan do you remove ng-controller , and do like me answer ?

Comment: @amitchauhan or you can remove read-only in file codepen? i try to help

Comment: i cant even find how to make it public

Comment: @amitchauhan so can you create another file and make it public ?

Comment: please check thisd

Comment: @amitchauhan just read only , but i know your problem . check my answer edit in route config .

Comment: @amitchauhan and if you still confuse , can you make another file in https://plnkr.co, i will help

Comment: it should be yourcontroller or profilecontroller in route config file

Comment: when i use controller : "profilecontroller" then routing not working lol

Comment: @amitchauhan what ever you like , but make sure it same name

Comment: @amitchauhan it not work because not same name , in config you use `profilecontroller` and in app.js you should use `profilecontroller` not `yourcontroller` and make sure you remove `ng-controller` in profile.php

Comment: i did whatever you said now routing not working i mean url changes but data not loading

Comment: <script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "dashboard.php"
    })
    .when("/profile", {
        templateUrl : "profile.php"
        controller : "yourcontroller"
    })
    .when("/downloads", {
        templateUrl : "downloads.php"
    });
});
</script>

Comment: this is my routing script

Comment: can you give me your codepen account? i try to help @amitchauhan

Comment: can u come to team view ?

Comment: @amitchauhan sr i cant , can you create another file in https://plnkr.co ?

Comment: @amitchauhan you can see here https://plnkr.co/edit/qVi5Yc5isS9TNJZl7RCJ?p=preview . It work perfect . Dont forget accept and vote for me ^^

Answer (score -1):

Use angular ng-show or ng-hide directive.

If in case you want to hide/show based on some interval/timeout you can use angular built-in services $timeout, $interval

```
$timeout(function () {    
    $scope.{model_name} = false;   
}, timeout_value);
```